# List Items Export to Excel on SharePoint 2013

Tags: excel, export

I have a list on SharePoint 2013 and I want to export the list items to excel file. How can I do export process?

Comment: you mean you want to do it through code? or just from list

Comment: I don't want code of list. I want to get list items only. @inferno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to List and in the ribbon bar you will see an export to excel button. Click on that will save data in excel. save the file with the default "owssvr.iqy".

Open it by double clicking, it will open in excel and then make some edit in the file like writing some text and then if you want delete it again and then save the file with .xlsx or xls extension. Now it will be and Excel file

Answer (score 0):

Go to List and on top of List you will see an export to excel button. Click on that will save data in excel.

Comment: I tried this but it export file as "owssvr.iqy". The file can't open. So I saved as excel this file and when I open the file I got this error  "Excel cannot open the file.. Because the file format or file extension is not valid.."   How can I export as excel?

Comment: Please refer to answer by @maos